# using php to encode characters for mailto in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, quotes, mailto

I am using `window.location.href = 'mailto:?body=visit http://example.com/?content=link';`

which works fine, but the way the link is built is `window.location.href = 'mailto:?body=<?php echo $content; ?>';`

now this works fine unless `$content` contains `'` or something similar which breaks the code.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `rawurlencode` function<sup>[[php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)]</sup> to encode any characters in your input that aren't valid in URLs.

```
<?php $content = "Hello, this' an...\n\nexample!"; ?>
window.location.href = "mailto:?body=<?php echo rawurlencode($content); ?>";
```

Output:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:?body=Hello%2C%20this%27%20an...%0A%0Aexample%21";
```

It is true that you normally would want to use `addslashes`<sup>[[php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)]</sup> when you're putting something in a quoted string. In this case it would have no effect because the output of `rawurlencode` doesn't have any characters that need to be escaped with slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php), which escapes the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php):

```
window.location.href = 'mailto:?body=<?php echo rawurlencode($content); ?>';
```